# Catching RealmSwift write errors i.e. delete

Tags: swift, realm

How exactly do I catch RealmSwift add/delete errors?

i.e.

```
do {
    try realm.write {
        realm.delete(MyRealmObject())
    }
    completion(true)
} catch {
    completion(false)
}
```

In this example I've deliberately tried deleting a RealmObject that I've just made up (to make it fail), but it doesn't catch, instead I get this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Can only delete an object from the Realm it belongs to.'

I haven't seen any examples of people handling specific delete/add errors - is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

Realm developers extend `NSError` class with their custom description `Can only delete an object from the Realm it belongs to` and do `FatalError` in the predefined list of errors they expect ( may be for a good use of the their library as a help to the developer to correctly use it ) , so they intentionally don't `throw` an exception that the `try` can `catch`

Comment: Thanks, Sh_Khan - would you be able to provide a Swift example of this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but the following code catches and identifies specific add errors. However, errors accessing different instances of realm are handled differently. So starting with this...

```
class MyObject: Object {
    @objc dynamic msg = ""
}

do {
    let realm = try Realm()

    let a0 = MyObject()
    a0.msg = "Hello, World"

    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(a0)
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

to then expand.... do the following to ensure the object being deleted matches the realm you are deleting it from.

```
    do {
        let realm = try Realm()

        if a0.realm == realm {
            try! realm.write {
                realm.delete(a0)
            }
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Jay, but it seems like any errors would stem from realm.write() rather than anything specifically related to an add/delete. It looks like realm.delete (for example) just throws exceptions because if it goes wrong, it'd be down to the developer misusing the API.

Comment: @LenaV The question states the error is being caused by the line with .delete, not by .write. You can verify that by commenting out `realm.delete(MyRealmObject())` and running the code. As you'll see, it works correctly without that line. The idea of my code is to proactive in ensuring the code won't crash instead of reacting to the crash. Much like using a guard statement to verify a var is not nil, or providing a default value when an optional is nil using a nil coalescing operator: ??. My code simple verifies the object is in the realm you're trying to delete it from, before deleting it.